# number of rows in two files different--> make equal by deleting from end

Tags: python, python-2.7, rows

```
 with open(filename,"r") as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
       data = list(reader)
       rownum = len(data)
 with open(filename2,"r") as f:
       reader2 = csv.reader2(f,delimiter = ",")
       data2 = list(reader2)
       rownum2 = len(data)

 if rownum > rownum2:
       delete(rownum until rownum = rownum2 at end)
```

Comment: need same dimensions to plot

Comment: So, what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.

```
data = data[:max(rownum, rownum2)]
data2 = data2[:max(rownum, rownum2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to save the new data? If so this will do the job and the files must not even be in csv format:

```
with open(filename1, "rb") as f:
    f1lines = f.readlines()

with open(filename2, "rb") as f:
    f2lines = f.readlines()

length = min(len(f1lines), len(f2lines))
f1lines = f1lines[:length]
f2lines = f2lines[:length]

with open(filename1, "wb") as f:
    for line in f1lines:
        f.write(line)

with open(filename2, "wb") as f:
    for line in f2lines:
        f.write(line)
```